# How can I simplify this series of target.write commands?

Tags: python

I'm working my way through Zed Shaw's "Learn Python The Hard Way". I'm up to exercise 16 ( http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex16.html ) and am running into a problem figuring out extra credit # 3. There are a series of 6 target.write commands towards the bottom of the script and Zed wants me to simplify them into a single target.write command using strings, formats and escapes.

Here is the original script with the 6 target.write commands...

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

print "We're going to erase %r." % filename
print "If you don't want that, hit CTRL-C (^C)."
print "If you do want that, hit RETURN."

raw_input("?")

print "Opening the file..."
target = open(filename, 'w')

print "Truncating the file.  Goodbye!"
target.truncate()

print "Now I'm going to ask you for three lines."

line1 = raw_input("line 1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line 2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line 3: ")

print "I'm going to write these to the file."

target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")

print "And finally, we close it."
target.close()
```

First I tried condensing the target.write commands like this...

```
target.write (line1, line2, line3)
```

When I run the script I get; TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

Then I tried...

```
target.write "I love %r and %r and %r." % (line1, line2, line3)
```

I get SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I also tried...

```
target.write (line1), (line2), (line3)
```

This time the script ran to competition without any errors, but when I open the file that the script is supposed to write to (text.txt) it only wrote the first string (line1) into the file, but not the other two strings (line2) and (line3).

Finally, I tried this...

```
target.write (line1, "\n", line2 "\n", line3, "\n")
```

But again I got an SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Can someone point me in the right direction on this?

Much appreciated.

Eddie

Comment: Just a nit-pick, your last one is probably a `TypeError`, not a `SyntaxError`.

Comment: mgilison, I just re-ran it and it is coming up as a Syntax error...

    File "ex16.py", line 25
    target.write (line1, "\n", line2 "\n", line3, "\n")
                                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You're correct, it is.  The syntax error is because you're missing a comma between `line2` and `"\n"`.  (which I didn't notice before).

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! Reading the 4 answers to this questions, I'm blown away by how many different ways there are in programming to achieve the same outcome. This is my first legit attempt at learning to code and the more options there seem to be, the harder it gets to grasp the concepts...for me anyway.

Comment: First I would try to grasp basic control structures (loops [`for`, `while`] , conditional statements [`if`], etc.).  The answer by @Marcin is good for that.  Once you get used to those things, you'll start to pick up things which are a little more python specific (like my answer) and it will eventually become more natural.  Just a note, the answers by Levon and codebox_ron are 2 variants of the same thing.  The one by Levon is the more modern way to do it whereas the one by codebox_rob is deprecated, but still commonly used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
target.write('\n'.join((line1,line2,line3))+'\n')
```

Or, maybe written a little more clearly:

```
lines=(line1,line2,line3)
target.write( '\n'.join(lines) + '\n')
```

Although, in this case, I might actually write the last newline separately to avoid the overhead of creating an entirely new string just to add on a newline at the end (and I think it looks cleaner):

```
lines=(line1, line2, line3)
target.write('\n'.join(lines))
target.write('\n')
```

This takes your lines, packs them together as a tuple and uses the `join` method of string objects to make them into a single string which gets written.

The advantage to this approach (as opposed to string formatting) is that you don't need to know *a-priori* how many "lines" you are going to write.  Any iterable object will do work in place of the tuple in the above expression.

Answer (score 2):

[write()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=write#file.write) wants a single `string` as parameter. You could try

```
 target.write (line1 + '\n' + line2 +'\n' + line3)  # ugly!! - but works
```

a better approach would be to build your string and then print it.

```
 line = '{}\n{}\n{}\n'.format(line1, line2, line3)
 target.write(line)
```

or dynamically join your string with `join()`, and several other ways to go about this, but this ought to get you started (and explain the cause of the problem).

Answer (score 2):

In general, any code which consists of repetition of the same operation with a defined sequence of data can be transformed into a loop which iterates over a collection of that data, and performs that operation in the loop. Accordingly, this:

```
target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")
```

becomes:

```
data = (line1, "\n", line2, "\n", line3, "\n")
for datum in data:
    target.write(datum)
```

Much better! Now, you only have one line of `write` code to change if you want to do something else (e.g. send to a different file, or use a different method). **See if you can work out a way to make this even better**.

However, there is another option: where you have an operation on several data which has the effect of concatenating that data, you can instead concatenate the data into a single datum and perform the operation once (*absolute novices:* note that if the operation does more than that, they might not be completely equivalent). In this case, that becomes:

```
data = (line1, "\n", line2, "\n", line3, "\n")
target.write(''.join(data))
```

Now, **take a look at the documentation for `join`, and figure out how you can simplify that further.** (Hint: it exploits the same fact about the data that simplifying the loop does).

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
target.write("%s\n%s\n%s\n" % (line1, line2, line3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a string:

> lines = "%s\n%s\n%s\n" % (line1, line2, line3)
>
> target.write(lines)

Answer (score 0):

I did

```
target.write("%s\n%s\n%s" % (line1, line2, line3 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
target.write('\n' .join((line1 , line2 , line3))+'\n')
```

Comment: Isn't that exactly the same as the first part of the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

target.write(""" line1 \n line2 \n line3 \n""")

Answer (score 0):

```
target.write(""" #{line1} \n #{line2} \n #{line3} \n""")
```

This is the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, give it a try

```
lines = " %s \n %s \n %s  \n"  %  (line1, line2, line3)

target.write(lines)
```